# How can we pass type, page_token,sorting etc… in google place IOS API?

Tags: ios, swift, google-places-api

With Web API we can pass type like

`"&type=restaurant|cafe|bar”&pagetoken=“mynextpagetoken”`

But with mobile API(GMSPlacesClient class) I don’t find any way to do this, I have gone with Place API framework. And find some places where people says that mobile API has more limitations then web APIs

Can you anyone suggest how to do this with Mobile API? As right now I’m using mobile API to add Place and to fetch places I’m using web-api.

Comment: is not `&&pagetoken` it is `&pagetoken`and try once

Comment: I mean with web-api its working fine but with mobile API we have Class named "GMSPlacesClient" but I can't pass which place i'm looking for?

Comment: Unfortunately Google is not allowing direct fetching of the places. Even though you can do that in web you never actually get the consistent results for the same query. I've noticed that when were trying to calculate the number of places by type in the specific area. 10 runs of the script gave me different numbers and more to that different places as results.

Comment: @inokey Load more places of any perticular types with mobile api seems not possible to me, its working fine with web api.

Answer (score 0):

To mimic the behaviour described in your question there's a separate class for that in iOS API: `GMSPlacePicker`

Documentation for that can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/placepicker).

**EDIT**

Looking through documentation for mobile API, there's no indication that such functionality exists. Clicking on 'search' in docs redirects to web API search docs. You'll have to use web API for fetching places.

Comment: I have document and framework, but i'm not able to apply load more places of any perticular types with mobile api, its working fine with web api.

Comment: You're correct. This functionality is not available in mobile API. It looks like you have to use web API for that and than use mobile API for specific places. But as I mentioned before, there's a huge chance of getting inconsistent data with web api.